# adding new sheet in Excel with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

How does one specify the options?
This works `$workbook.worksheets.Add()` but I want to specify a worksheet to add this new one after. That's the second of four possible options:.Add(Before, After, Count, Type). I can't seem to figure out what the proper syntax in Powershell is. If I get it wrong, there's no error, but the worksheet is not created. For example, `$workbook.worksheets.Add(,$lastSheet)` does not work. $lastSheet of course is a sheet object. I instantiated that with `$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet
$lastSheet = $sheet`

Comment: I tried to figure this out once, and eventually gave up and just created the sheet at the default location and moved it later.

Answer (score 2):

```
$workbook.worksheets.Add([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value,$lastsheet)
```

Apparently the `[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value` can be used to represent a value in this kind of construction because a null is not allowed.

Comment: Kind of janky. I wonder if there is a better way to do this kind of stuff with Office applications. Write it in VBA and then call that somehow with Powershell? I don't know if that would flow anyway.